# Android Studio; Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, mobile-application

I am new to android studio and I have got this error while trying to create my first project.

```
Gradle Daemon started in 11 s 663 ms
File C:\Users\Night Raven\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\Night Raven\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\Night Raven\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.
CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 11m 42s
```

I will be glad for your help

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk8B9.png)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681045/error-module-app-platform-android-28-not-found-and-design-editor-is-unava

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Kindly allow me a suggestion: It is better to upload an image directly into the questions, since  link addresses may change over time.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh  for the solutions .@rainer I have uninstalled android studio and re installed it while connected to the internet . The SDK and other tools were downloaded and updated automatically . its now working .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)